# goquery insert newline after text found

Tags: goquery

I am using "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery" to parse numbers from inside 'value' tag in the html document like below

```
<tab>
<value>1,2,3</value>
<value>2,4,6</value>
<value>5,6,7</value>
</tab>
```

and what I got with code snippet below is 1,2,32,4,65,6,7 so without newline which is not what I want . I need multiple 3 'values'(to append each of them later to slice) not one

```
func parseGoQuery(b io.Reader) {
    doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(b)    
    fmt.Println(doc.Find("tab").Find("value").Text())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
doc.Find("tab").Find("value").Each(func(_ int, value *goquery.Selection) {
    fmt.Println(value.Text())
})
```

The above code iterates over all *value* elements, and then print the text of each element in one line, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Code-only answers are not very helpful.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.